# cannot perform __truediv__ with this index type: DatetimeArray

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

What does this error mean? My Date column is in the following format - [datetime64[ns]

one of the post on here states that you: "As the error stated, this happens due to the Date column. If you tried to get the covariance matrix with all other columns, it will work just fine. If you want to use the Date column, you can convert the date to the number of seconds and everything will work just fine"

I am not sure why 1) this error shows and 2) what needs to be done.

Date              datetime64[ns]
N LN Equity            float64
A LN Equity            float64
AS LN Equity            float64
AV LN Equity            float64
BRE LN Equity           float64

The error comes when I apply the following:

```
cov_matrix=df.pct_change().apply(lambda x: np.log(1+x)).cov()
cov_matrix
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: cannot perform \_\_truediv\_\_ with this index type: DatetimeArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114967/typeerror-cannot-perform-truediv-with-this-index-type-datetimearray)